# On a Tumble Check to avoid Attacks of Opportunity, do you move at half speed for your whole movement?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, movement

**Tumble DC 15**

> Tumble at one-half speed as part of normal movement, provoking no attacks of opportunity while doing so. Failure means you provoke attacks of opportunity normally. Check separately for each opponent you move past, in the order in which you pass them (player’s choice of order in case of a tie). Each additional enemy after the first adds +2 to the Tumble DC.

How are the rules on movement interpreted correctly?

1. You move at half speed for your entire move action.
2. You move at half speed through every threatened square and at normal speed through non-threatened squares (as if moving through normal and difficult terrain.)

Comment: Related: [Is a new tumble check made for each threatened square](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128789/is-a-new-tumble-check-made-for-each-threatened-square)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, it costs double to move through a threatened square

This was clarified on the [3.5 FAQ](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20070731a), which the community has mixed opinions about (as seen on [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60044/what-is-wrong-with-the-dd-3-5-faq)):

> For example, imagine Ember begins her turn 10 feet from an orc and wants to use Tumble to move through its space and end up 15 feet away on the opposite side.
>
> Her first square of movement wouldn’t provoke attacks of opportunity (since she’s not leaving a threatened square), so she doesn’t use Tumble or move at half speed.
>
> Her second and third squares of movement take her through the orc’s space, so these effectively cost twice normal (that is, they each cost 1 extra square of movement), and this movement requires a DC 25 Tumble check. (If you’re using this system, it’s much easier to think of tumbling as **costing extra squares of movement rather than actually changing your speed**.) Ember has now paid a total of 5 squares of movement (out of the 8 allotted to her for her speed of 40 feet).
>
> Assuming that check succeeds, Ember now moves from a threatened square (adjacent to the orc), which requires a DC 15 Tumble check and costs twice normal (or 1 extra square of movement). She’s now paid a total of 7 squares of movement.
>
> Finally, Ember moves one last square, ending up 15 feet from the orc on the opposite side from where she began. She’s not leaving a threatened square, so she doesn’t use Tumble or pay any extra movement. Ember has paid for 8 squares (40 feet) of movement, and has covered a linear distance of 5 squares (25 feet).